# Is there any tool out there for Linux to view open windows like Gnome and windows?

Tags: linux, xfce, panel, compiz

I want a button in xfce to show me open windows (minimized and maximized) like

- *Exposé* (later *Mission Control*) in Mac OS
- *Activites* in Gnome or
- *Task View* in Windows 10.

I found some tools like *Xfdashboard* and *Skippy-xd* but they need compiling from source and I get errors from compiling them and I am new to Linux.

Now I use the *compiz* scale. It is good actually, but it only shows maximized windows. It doesn't show minimized windows and the shift switcher compiz has two modes, "cover" and "flip". Both of them aren't my interests. I want them to show like a grid.
Finally, I want to say the Activities button is needed for fast switching windows and productivity.

My Linux is MX Linux 21_x64 wildflower Xfce-desktop.
I have only 4GB of RAM, Gnome and Ubuntu use too much memory. That's why I use Xfce and this is what I want a button to open running applications like these:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us what Linux distribution you are using and ii) maybe include a screenshot of the kind of thing you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I think I explained everything and there is no need for pictures, but now I have updated my post.

Comment: Have you read https://mxlinux.org/wiki/applications/hotcorner/? That seems to suggest that skippy is in the MX linux repositories and you don't need to compile.

Comment: Thanks for your link, I took some steps to install but did not succeed when I installed python-xlib and python3-xlib successfully, but when I ran this bl-hotcorners –daemon & in terminal it gave me this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bl-hotcorners", line 21, in <module>
    from xlib import display
ImportError: No module named xlib

Comment: Better open another question for this, because this is different from the original question and needs to attract different people.

Comment: I did install xfdashboard, but it is slow. and for skippy-xd, it's not exist in Synaptic manager. Is there any tool exist beside xfdashboard and skippy-xd

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>↓ Down</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut in Mint to show all open windows.

Another easy alternative is enable a hot corner.  Press the Super key (aka Windows key) and start typing h-o-t . . .  until you see "Hot Corners" show up in the menu, then select it.  One of the first options you'll see for Hot Corners is `Show the window selection screen`.  To use a Hot Corner once enabled, you just slide your mouse to that corner and it will perform that command (also available in Mac OS).

Either of these methods will show all windows regardless of whether they're minimized.  Note this shortcut will do other things in other distros or operating systems, so it is somewhat Mint specific.